# Several lines of code with "$" errors

Tags: math-mode, errors, algorithms, algorithm2e

How could I get rid of these errors?

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn

\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof

%\usepackage[english]{babel} %%% 'french', 'german', 'spanish', 'danish', etc.
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[linesnumbered, ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
    content\begin{algorithm}
        %\DontPrintSemicolon
        \SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
        \SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
        \Input{Total = W\\
            Total cycles = cyc $_{total}$\\
            f$_{Cyc}$ = Q : Area\\
            $\left( x{}_{Sk},y{}_{Sk} \right)$ : Sk\\
            $\alpha$= Parameter1 \\

        }
        \Output{ Xi $\leftarrow$ rand(0,1)*Q\\

        }

        \For{each, i}{$Z_{O} = 450\\ Li \leftarrow  sqrt \left( \left( x_{i}-x_{Sk}\right)^2 + \left( y_{i}-y_{Sk}\right) ^2\right) $}      
        $L_{ave}\leftarrow\left( sum \left(L_{i} \right) \right) / n$\space // Parameter Sk \\

    $L{}_{Tr} \leftarrow \alpha * L_{ave }$
        // First Parameter based\\
    \end{algorithm}...
\end{document}
```

The svjour3class is based on Springers template for articles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were missing several `$` symbols to either initiate or terminate math mode.

Some additional suggestions:

- No need to load `fix-cm` and `txfonts` since you later load `kpfonts`.
- Don't overuse `\left` and `\right`, unless you thrive on code clutter.
- Encase subscript material that should *not* be in math italics in `\text{...}` directives.

Separately, should it be "`Xi`" (the uppercase Greek character) or "`X_{i}`" ("X sub i")? If the latter, it should also be placed in math mode.

[image]

```
%%%%%\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}   % from http://www.e-publications.org/springer/support/spr-chicago.html

\smartqed  % flush-right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%%%%\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
%%%%\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[linesnumbered, ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    %\DontPrintSemicolon
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
    \SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
    \Input{Total = W\\
            Total cycles = cycr$_{\text{total}}$\\
            f$_{\text{Cyc}}$ = Q : Area\\
            $( x_{\text{Sk}},y_{\text{Sk}} )$ : Sk\\
            $\alpha$ = Parameter1 \\
          }
    \Output{ Xi $\leftarrow$ rand(0,1)*Q\\
           }
    \For{each i}{
           $Z_{0} = 450$\\ % _{0} rather than _{O}, right?
           $L_i \leftarrow  sqrt \left( ( x_{i}-x_{\text{Sk}})^2 + 
               ( y_{i}-y_{\text{Sk}}) ^2\right) $
           }
    $L_{\text{ave}}\leftarrow$ (sum ($L_{i}$) ) / $n$\quad // Parameter Sk \\
    $L_{\text{Tr}} \leftarrow \alpha * L_{\text{ave}}$\quad // First Parameter based\\
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution.

Replace  `\For{each, i}{$Z_{O} = 450\\ Li \leftarrow` with `\For{each, i}{$Z_{O} = 450$\; $Li \leftarrow`

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn

\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof

%\usepackage[english]{babel} %%% 'french', 'german', 'spanish', 'danish', etc.
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[linesnumbered, ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
    content\begin{algorithm}
        %\DontPrintSemicolon
        \SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
        \SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
        \Input{Total = W\\
            Total cycles = cyc $_{total}$\\
            f$_{Cyc}$ = Q : Area\\
            $\left( x{}_{Sk},y{}_{Sk} \right)$ : Sk\\
            $\alpha$= Parameter1 \\

        }
        \Output{ Xi $\leftarrow$ rand(0,1)*Q\\

        }

        \For{each, i}{$Z_{O} = 450$\; $Li \leftarrow  sqrt \left( \left( x_{i}-x_{Sk}\right)^2 + \left( y_{i}-y_{Sk}\right) ^2\right) $}      
        $L_{ave}\leftarrow\left( sum \left(L_{i} \right) \right) / n$\space // Parameter Sk \\

    $L{}_{Tr} \leftarrow \alpha * L_{ave }$
        // First Parameter based\\
    \end{algorithm}...
\end{document}
```

Comment: `Z_{O}` ("Big Oh") should probably be written as `Z_{0}` ("zero"), right?

Comment: Yes you could by right, but i have no idea.